# Proving $\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} \cos (tx) \ dt$ is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Prove that $f$ defined on $\mathbb R$ and given by $f(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} \cos (tx) \ dt$ is differentiable.

Fix $a\in \mathbb R,$ then
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}
&=\lim_{h\to 0} \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\cdot  \dfrac{\cos(at+ht)-\cos(at)}{h}\ dt.
\end{align}

If I can use LCT, I can change the $\lim$ and $\int$ since the integrand is not grater than $|te^{-t^2}|$ and $te^{-t^2}$ is Lebesgue-integrable on $[0, \infty]$ and come to the conclusion.

But this problem doesn't suppose the knowledge about Lebesgue integral theory. Thus this seems to be solved without using the  knowledge about Lebesgue integral theory.

Is there the reason why I can change $\lim$ and $\int$ without Lebesgue integral theory, or the reason why $f$ is differentiable ?

Comment: Interchanging the integral and limit in this context is called the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: Perhaps use $\cos(at+ht)-\cos(at) = -2\sin (a t + ht/2) \sin (ht/2)$ then the integral split into some parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t,x) = \cos(tx)$. By mean value theorem for some $y\in [x, x+h]$, we have

$$|\frac{f(t, x+h)-f(t,x)}{h}-f_x(t,x)|=|t\cdot \sin(ty) - t \sin(tx)|\le |t||ty-tx|\le |t|^2|h|$$

(We have used $|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\le |x-y|$ which also follows from MVT.)

Then as $h\rightarrow 0$,
$$|\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} [\frac{f(t, x+h) - f(t, x)}{h} -f_x(t,x)]dt|$$ $$\le \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} t^2 |h|dt=(\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}t^2dt)|h|\rightarrow 0$$

This can be done because $e^{-t^2}$ is too dominant.
In general, without any Lebesgue theory, we have the following general result (as usual, uniform conergence is needed):

> Let $f(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$ be both continuous on
> $[a,\infty)\times[c,d]$, such that
>
> (1) $I(y)=\int_a^\infty f(x,y)dx$ converges for $y\in [c,d]$.
>
> (2) $J(y)=\int_a^\infty f_y(x,y)dx$ converges uniformly for $y\in [c,d]$.
>
> Then $I(y)$ is continuously differentiable on $[c,d]$ and $\frac{dI(y)}{dy}=J(y)$.